# Selenium Web driver button with java

Tags: java, html, selenium

I would like my web driver to pick a button called **Allow** from a page I am trying to automate. Here is the **div** :

```
<td>
    <button id="itbtnPagar"onclick="javascript:master_pagar_giro(320535,&quot;67085703b3fa5ef2aab2d1596b364441e021cd79&quot;);"class="botones" type="button"> Allow </button>
</td>
```

Here is the pojo excerpt:

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMain_ctBusquedaPagador1_txtReceipt")).isSelected())
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMain_ctBusquedaPagador1_txtReceipt")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);

    if (driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMain_ctBusquedaPagador1_txtReceipt")).isSelected())
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("itbtnPagar")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("botones")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    if (driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMain_ctBusquedaPagador1_txtReceipt")).isSelected())
    {
        driver.quit();
        return;
    }
}
```

How do I enable selenium to click on that button **Allow** in order to produce an event. Kindly assist.

Comment: 1- please format your code to readable format 2- what is the problem with what you have?

Comment: The id of the button is unique? The execution enters the if with this click?

Comment: @Guy I hope you are now able to read the code clearly. The problem I am having is on what element should I pick from the `<button>` tag and match it successfully with the objects in the pojo excerpt above. I have tried using **id** without success.

Comment: @lauda in this case, I am asking how to match the element in the `<button>` tag with java elements

Comment: Well, now it even less readable. Can you read it like this? About your problem, do you have any errors? where does it fails?

Comment: Try by css with: #itbtnPagar[onclick*=master_pagar_giro]

Comment: @Guy there is no error thrown on the logs

Comment: @lauda I am interested in an example code mapping the css above  to java to demonstrate your suggestion.

Comment: It should be something like this: driver.findElement(By.CssSelector(" #itbtnPagar[onclick*=master_pagar_giro]")).click();

Comment: Can you explain a little about what the scenario is that you are trying to accomplish? I see that you are checking if an element is selected and clicking it often... what is your scenario?

Comment: @JeffC how can you make selenium web driver to click a button built using the above html

Comment: No, that's not really the scenario or you wouldn't need all that other code besides `driver.findElement(By.id("itbtnPagar")).click();`. So why do you have all the `if`s and all the other code? You need to better explain your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@id, 'ibtnPagar') and contains(@type, 'button')]))".click();
```

Comment: I will try it out though I had closed on that project. I still value your input

Answer (score 0):

why you can't just click on it by id ?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("itbtnPagar")).click();
```

you can also grub onclick value and invoke it with js ExecuteScript

to initialize js you need first init your driver and after that:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

string scriptToExecute = driver.findElement(By.id("itbtnPagar").getAttribute("onclick");
js.executeScript(scriptToExecute);
```

Comment: I really like your approach on this issue I am experiencing. Just a clarification from you. How has `js` been used there?

Comment: I tried that approach, but still no success. I will do a modification to it for any positive result. FYI. no error is thrown